# Speed of electron and proton in electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electrons, electric-fields

Speed of electron and proton in electric field.

In a uniform electric field E, the acceleration of an electron in vacuum is 1836 times that of a proton (proton/electron mass ratio is 1836). I'll like to know if any direct experiment has been done to prove this. By direct, I mean actually measuring a final speed and not some indirect prove from energy consideration.

Comment: Measuring the energy of a particle is a very good way to measure its speed, given that we know its mass.  For an elementary particle such as an electron or proton there really is no other way.  Each interaction with matter, or an electromagnetic may change its speed.
You can send it through a constant magnetic field and measure the deflection.  That measures momentum $mv$ and thus still requires knowledge of the mass.